# nginx with round robin for all routes but for one route forward request to all listed ip's

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a Api deployed on two server which is being served via ngnix round robin.
In the Address there is a one route on which i want to froward request to both servers instead of round robin
is it possible?
My configuration is as following

```
upstream mynginxurl {
    server  10.10.10.1:8080;
    server  10.10.10.2:8080;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.100.200.300;

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://mynginxurl;
            proxy_next_upstream error http_502;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            server_tokens off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            client_max_body_size       25m;
            client_body_buffer_size    256k;
            proxy_connect_timeout     180;
            proxy_send_timeout        180;
            proxy_read_timeout        180;
            proxy_buffer_size          128k;
            proxy_buffers              4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            proxy_buffering on;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/mynginxurl_access_log ;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/mynginxurl_error_log notice;
    }
}
```

For http://10.100.200.300/MyRoute/MyMethod address i wanted to forward the request to both server

Comment: What does it mean “forward the request to both servers”? Your client must receive an HTTP answer which can be provided only by one of servers.

Comment: one request generally forwarded by round robin or other method to one server. i was checking if one request can be forwarded to multiple nodes depending on it's address.

Comment: So, you want to forward request from one set of ip addresses to one server and from other addresses to another one, don’t you?